# How to detect when a button is pressed 3 times using commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minecraft adventure map, and its an army game and I'm having trouble giving the boss at the end health. It's a tank, and it has a self destruct button, but I want to make so you have to press it 3 times to win. I'm using a scoreboard command.

At the start of the map it sets the health to 1. I used this:

```
/scoreboard players set @a Tank 1
```

At the end, you press the self destruct button and it should add 1, and when it gets to 4, it should end. When you press the self destruct button, it runs the command:

```
/scoreboard players add 1 Tank
```

And I used a `/testfor` command that's supposed to test for the score at 4. I used:

```
/testfor @p[score_Tank=4]
```

And for the command I used to add the scoreboard was:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Tank dummy
```

Can someone find the command I did wrong and correct it?

Answer (score 2):

`score_<objective>=#` is checking for a maximum score, which means `score_Tank=4` is looking for a score of 4 *or lower*. You'll want to use `score_<objective>_min=#` to check for a minimum score, so that it'll check for a score of 4 or higher:

```
/testfor @p[score_Tank_min=4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Skylinerw, is right, but you also made a mistake in the scoreboard players add command there is no selector, therefor it will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this in chat
/scoreboard objectives add Tank dummy
Command at the start of the map
/scorboard players set @a Tank 0
Command for the button
/scoreboard players add @p Tank 1
Command for the testfing command block
/execute @a[score_Tank_min=3] ~ ~ ~ [command you want when score is 3 (use @s to only target the player with the score of 3) for example */kill @s*]

The Command will be executed after pressing the button three times.